# How do you easily go to the next item inside an Array?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm creating a random word generator which will contain a lot of words. I'm using the following code:

```
function gentext() {
var word=['example', 'word', '', '' , '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',];
var para=document.querySelector('p');
para.innerHTML=word[Math.floor(Math.random()*word.length)];
}
```

In between the apostrophes I need to fill in all the other words to come. Is there an easy way to go immediately between the apostrophes instead of using the right arrow key several times inside Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I'd suggest writing the words in a long list one per line and then adding cursor to all lines at once and adding the quotes and the commas, followed by deleting the newlines. (Select all the lines, F1, "Add cursor to line ends", Home, `'`, End, `'`, `,`, Space, Del)

Comment: Oh yes! That would save me a lot of time. You are a Saint, thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a small code for it, for example write all your words in a single string : `

```js
let str = "word example cat dog eats monkey node angular javascript";

const word = str.split(" ");
console.log(word)
```

And you have your array as word.